# Why do almost all OO languages compile to bytecode?

Tags: oop, compiler-construction, programming-languages, bytecode

Of the object-oriented languages I know, pretty much all but C++ and Objective-C compile to bytecode running on some sort of virtual machine. Why have so many different languages settled on compiling to bytecode, as opposed to machine code? Is it possible in princible to have a high-level memory-managed OOP language that compiled to machine code?

Edit: I'm aware that multiplatform support is often advanced as an advantage of this approach. However, it's quite possible to compile natively on multiple platforms, without making a new compiler per platform. One can, per example, emit C code and then compile that with GCC.

Comment: I guess this is because they are intended for efficiency, and bytecode/VM almost always comes with a performance tradeoff. Note, however, that both C++ and Objective-C compile to LLVM bytecode that afterwards can be converted to native code.

Comment: @Diego: In *some* implementations. `gcc` doesn't compile to LLVM, and I'm pretty sure Visual Studio doesn't either.

Comment: @sepp2k: I don't understand what do you mean with "gcc doesn't compile to LLVM". LLVM is able to compile C, C++, and Objective-C to bytecode and to native code afterwards (of course, in some platforms) by itself.

Comment: @Diego: I mean that while clang uses LLVM, gcc does not. So saying "C++ compiles to LLVM" is misleading because it makes it sound as if all or most C++ implementations compiled to LLVM.

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to link bytecode/VM based languages with OOP. As you have notes yourself, C++ and Objective-C do not use VMs. Rather it is more of a trend in newer languages, which also happen to have good OOP support. IMHO, just because the two occur together, it does not mean one implies the other.

Comment: @sepp2k `gcc` can use LLVM if you want it to.  Check out the [dragonegg](http://dragonegg.llvm.org/).

Comment: emitting c code is possible but its a bit of a nightmare.. works well for small projects. .  Another benefit of a bytecode interpreter is no or a light toolchain. Thus making it more suitable for users.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no reason in fact, this is a kind of coincidence. OOP now is the leading concept in "big" programming, and so virtual machines are.

Also note, that there are 2 distinct parts of traditional virtual machines - **garbage collector** and **bytecode interpreter/JIT-compiler**, and these parts can exist separately. For example, Common Lisp implementation called SBCL compiles program to a native code, but at runtime heavily uses garbage collection.

Comment: I think you meant "heavily" instead of "hardly" in your last sentence.

Answer (score 13):

This is done to allow a VM or JIT compiler the chance to compile the code on demand optimally for the architecture on which the code is executed. Also, it allows for cross-platform bytecode to be created once and then executed on multiple hardware architectures. This allows for hardware specific optimizations to be placed into the compiled code.

Since byte code is not limited to a microarchitecture, it can be smaller than machine code. Complex instructions can be represented vs. the much more primitive instructions available in modern day CPUs, since the constraints in the design of CPU instructions are very different from the constraints in designing a bytecode architecture.

Then there's the issue of security. The bytecode can be verified and analyzed prior to execution (i.e., no buffer overflows, variables of a certain type being accessed as something they are not), etc...

Comment: These are compelling features of VM - but they are nearly orthogonal to OOP.

Comment: Verification is not necessarily possible, the byte code must have been designed to allow it.

Answer (score 4):

Java uses bytecode because two of its initial design goals were portability and compactness. Those both came from the initial vision of a language for embedded devices, where fragments of code could be downloaded on the fly.

Python, Ruby, Smalltalk, javascript, awk and so on use bytecode because writing a native compiler is a lot of work, but a textual interpreter is too slow - bytecode hits a sweet spot of being fairly easy to write, but also satisfactorily quick to run.

I have no idea why the Microsoft languages use bytecode, since for them, neither portability nor compactness is a big deal. A lot of the thinking behind the CLR came out of computer scientists in Cambridge, so i imagine considerations like ease of program analysis and verification were involved.

Note that as well as C++ and Objective C, Eiffel, Ada 9X, Vala and Go are OO languages (of varying vintage) that are compiled straight to native code.

All in all, i'd say that OO and bytecode do not go hand in hand. Rather, we have a coincidental convergence of several streams of development: the traditional bytecoded interpreters of scripting languages like Python and Ruby, the mad Gosling masterplan of Java, and whatever it is Microsoft's motives are.

Comment: Microsoft's .Net runs on non-PC architectures as well - Xbox360 and Windows Mobile 7, hence portability.

Comment: I suppose .Net compiles to bytecode for cross-language compatibility

Comment: @thelaststud: Yes, that's probably it.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest reason why most interpreted languages (not specifically OO languages) are compiled to bytecode is for performance.  The most expensive part of interpreting code is transforming text source to an intermediate representation.  For instance, to perform something like:

```
foo + bar;
```

The interpreter would have to scan 10 characters, transform them into 4 tokens, build an AST for the operation, resolve three symbols (+ is a symbol, which depends on the types of foo and bar), all before it can perform any action that actually depends on the run-time state of the program.  None of this can change from run to run, and so many languages try to store some form of intermediate representation.

bytecode, rather than storing an AST has a few advantages.  For one, bytecodes are easy to serialize, so the IR can be written to disk and reused at the next invocation, further reducing interpretation time.  Another reason is that bytecode often takes up less actual ram.  significantly bytecode representations are often easy to just in time compile, because they are often structurally similar to typical machine code.

Comment: Translation of text to an intermediate representation is often not the most expensive part of compilation.  I think a bigger issue relates to lookups.  If code in one class file used a field of a class defined in another, and both files were stored as text, resolution of a single the field access could require scanning the entire second file.  A bytecode file, by contrast, can include a list of fields defined in a class and their addresses, as well as a list of foreign-class fields which are accessed; the runtime can use both lists to build in memory a list of foreign-class field addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Bytecode is significantly more flexible medium than machine code.  First, it provides the basis for platform portability without the need for a compiler or shipping source code.  So a developer can distribute a single version of the application without needing to give up the source, require complex developer tools, or anticipate potential target platforms.  While the later is not always practical it does happen.  Especially with developer libraries say I distribute a library that I've only tested on Windows, but someone else uses it on Linux or Android.  It happens quite frequently actually, and most of the time it works as expected.

Byte code is also generally more optimized that an interpreter because it's closer to machine instructions therefore faster to translate to machine instructions.  Not all OO languages are compiled.  Ruby, <strike>Python</strike>, and even Javascript are interpreted so they aren't compiled to anything so the ruby interpreter has to take a very flexible language and turn that into instructions, but that flexibility comes at a price paid an runtime: parse text, generate AST, translate AST to machine code, etc.  It's also easy to do optimizations like JIT where byte code is translated to machine code directly, and even gives the possibility for creating optimizations for specific hardware.

Finally, just because one language compiles to bytecode doesn't preclude other languages taking advantage of of that byte code.  Now any optimization using that byte code can be applied to these other languages that might know how to translate themselves to that byte code.  That makes the byte code a very important layer for reusability for other languages.

OO and byte code compilation goes back to the 70s with Smalltalk, and I'm sure someone will say LISP as early as the 50s/60s.  But, it really wasn't until the 90s that it started to really be used in production systems on a large scale.

Native compilation sounds like the optimal path, and probably why our industry spent 20 years or more thinking that was THE ANSWER to all our problems, but the last 15 years we've seen byte code compilation take stage and it's been a significant advantage over what we did before.  Looking back we realize how much time wasted natively compiling everything mostly by hand.

Comment: LUA compiles to bytecode, and runs on a VM, but is just as flexible as Javascript, as far as program structuring goes.  I believe (at least some) LISP implementations do this, as well.

Comment: Python _is_ compiled. This happens when you run the script, if it didn't happen earlier.

Comment: hmm, i take issue with juxtaposing byte code vs "interpeter" because byte code (AKA p-code) is executed by an interpreter - even if you call that a VM. You mean "pure interpretation" there. Also, Javascript is not necessarily only pure interpreter - Google Chrome *compiles* JS to native code (lookup V8 Javascript engine). Ruby has a bytecode interpreter nowadays too, the so called YARV (vs previous MRI).

Comment: There are key difference between byte code and interpreters.  Interpreters have to parse source code and build ASTs in order to interpret and validate code.  Bytecode does not.  Even interpreting the cached AST performs far worse than byte code.  Calling byte code an interpreter is vastly under estimating the performance of byte code vs. interpreters.  While most languages are now byte code optimized they did not start out that way.  Early versions of Javascript, LUA, Python, and Perl did not start out with byte code.  Ruby only got YARV in the last two years of it's almost 20 year life.

Answer (score 1):

As another data point, [the D programming language](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/) is GC'ed, OO, and a lot higher level than C++ while still being compiled to native code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Chubbard's answer and I'd add that in OO languages type information can be very important for enabling optimizations by virtual-machines or last-level compilers

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to develop an interpreter than a compiler.

Effort in development of...:

interpreter < bytecode-interpreter < bytecode-jit-compiler < compiler-to-platform-independent-language < compiler-to-multiple-machine-dependent-assembler.

It is a general trend to stop the development at jit-compilers because of platform independence. Only the preferred languages in respect to performance and research in theoretical computer science are and will be developed in ALL possible directions, including new bytecode-interpreter, even while there are good and advanced compilers to platform independent languages and to different machine-dependant assemblers.

The research in OOP languages is pretty ...let's say dull, compared to functional languages, because really new language and compiler technologies are more easily expressed with/in/using mathematical cathegory theory and mathematical descriptions of touring-complete type-systems. In other words: it is nearly functional in itself, while imperative languages are nearly only assembler-frontends with some syntactic sugar. OOP languages tend to be imperative languages, because functional languages have already closures and lambda. There are other ways to implement java-like "interfaces" in functional languages, and there is just no need for additional object oriented features.

In i.e. Haskell, adding the feature of OOP-like programming would probably be more than only a few steps back in technology – there would be no point in using that. (<- that is not only IMHO... you ever heard of GADTs or Multi-parameter-type-classes?) Probably there might be even better ways to dynamically create Objects with Interfaces to communicate with OOP-languges than changing that language itself. But there are other functional languages, too, that explicitely combine functional and OOP aspects. There is just more science with mainly functional languages than non-functional OO-languages.

OO languages can not be easily compiled to other OO languages, iff they are in some way more "advanced". Usually, they have features like stack-protector, advanced debugging abilities, abstract and inspectable multi-threading, dynamic object-loading from files from the internet... Many of these features are not or not-easily realisable with C or C++ as compiler-backend. The functional language LISP (which is 50 years old!) was AFAIK the first with garbage collector. As compiler-backend LISP used a hacked version of the language C, because plain C did not allow some of those things, assembler did allow, i.e. proper-tail-calls or tables-next-to-code. C-- allows that.

An other aspect: Imperative languages are intended to run on a specific architecture, i.e. C and C++ programs run on only those architectures, they are programmed for. Java is more extreme: it runs only on a single architecture, a virtual one, which itself runs on others.
Functional languages are usually by design pretty architecture-independent: LISP was developed to be so immense architecture-unspecific, that it could be compiled to genetic code, in some distant future. Yes, like programs running in living biologic cells.

With the bytecode for the LLVM, functional languages will most-likely be compiled to bytecode in the future, too. Most imperative languages will most likely still have the same inherited problems as they have now from not-abstracting-far-enough. Well, I'm not that sure about clang and D, but those two are not "the most" anyway.

Comment: Just as a side note, reading this would be better if you fixed your spelling.

Comment: Ironically, I don't understand the meaning of your suggestion. I'm no natural english speaker; what does "(to) fix spelling" mean?

Comment: @slomojo - What he means is that your answer has lot of spelling mistakes IE: **cathegory->category**

Comment: I disagree with your ease hierarchy. bytecode interpreters are easier to write than pure interpreters, and JITs are harder to write than to-machine-language compilers.

Comment: oh, I meant bytecode interpreter + to-bytecode-compiler. With the JIT-compiler, that depends on how far and where it optimizes the code: A JIT-compiler itself could be written to run compiled, interpreted, or self-optimizing at runtime via an other JIT-compiler. The last case does not need to compile to machine code, instead it might just fuse its own (partially) compiled routines. For example, it is really easy to write a LISP-to-LISP (JIT-)compiler in LISP or any other functional language – even with different LISP-dialects.